# The type 'ServiceCollection' exists in same dependencies but in different version

Tags: c#, asp.net

The error description is as below:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

Error   CS0433  The type 'ServiceCollection' exists in both 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

I am having this error suddenly, I had tried several steps but the error wont go off.
Some steps that I had tried:

1. Unload and reload project
2. Clean and rebuild solution
3. Delete obj and bin folder and rebuild solution once again

Someone know how to solve this issue?

[image: Error Image]

Comment: You can't just hope that it goes away. You need to look at the actual dependencies. It would appear that you have mismatched versions in your NuGet packages for the application. Make sure that all your NuGet packages are appropriate for the .NET version you're targeting. It sounds like you have a v6 package somewhere and a v5 package somewhere else. If you're targeting .NET 6, make sure that all your first-party packages are v6.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I managed to solve it by changing my target framework to v6 and rebuild the solution to make it works.

Comment: It's better to target .NET 6 than .NET 5 now anyway, as .NET 5 support will run out fairly quickly while .NET 6 will get long-term support. Not a big deal for learning projects but if you just stick with .NET 6 all the time then you won't get any surprises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment on the original post was really helpful

I had the same issue and managed to resolve it by targeting .NET 6.0

Probably best to ready ourselves to point all of our .NET 5.0 projects to .NET 6.0 anyway since .NET 5.0 is being deprecated

Answer (score 11):

Add this line to your project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
```

It helped me.

Comment: I had a previous release of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection referenced.  Updating to 6.0.0 fixed my problem.